# Creating nested JSON in PHPMyAdmin--PHP--Angular Pipeline

Tags: php, angularjs, json, phpmyadmin

So I'm sort of reaching the limit of my (limited) database knowledge here, but essentially I have a database set up as follows:

TABLE_NAME: Concepts;
FIELD_NAMES: id, meta_id

TABLE_NAME: Definitions;
FIELD_NAMES: id, concept_id, description, language_id

TABLE_NAME: Languages;
FIELD_NAMES: id, description, concept_id

Essentially, I have a list of Concepts (and their ids) and I need to display a list of Definitions.

So in my controller, I have something like:

```
exampleControllers.controller('conceptCtrl', ['$scope', 'SharedProperties', '$http', '$location', '$resource', function ($scope, SharedProperties, $http, $location, $resource) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.queryUrl = $location.search();
        SharedProperties.setQuery($scope.queryUrl);

        var ids_filtered, conceptIds;

        ids_filtered = SharedProperties.getQuery().id.split(",").filter(Boolean);

        conceptIds = {
            'id' : ids_filtered
        };

        $scope.query_string = SharedProperties.getQuery().query_string;

        console.log(conceptIds);

        $http.post("http://127.0.0.1/php/query_concepts.php", JSON.stringify(conceptIds))
            .then(function (response) {

                var data, status, statusText, headers, config, vm;

                data = response.data;
                status = response.status;
                statusText = response.statusText;
                headers = response.headers;
                config = response.config;

                vm = this;

                $scope.concepts = data;

                $resource($scope.concepts).query().$promise.then(function (concepts) {
                    vm.concepts = concepts;
                });

            });
    };

    $scope.getDefinitions = function (concept_id) {
        var queryData, result;

        $scope.query = concept_id;

        queryData = {
            "query_string": $scope.concept_id
        };

        $http.post("http://127.0.0.1/php/query_definitions.php", JSON.stringify(queryData))
            .then(function (response) {

                var data, status, statusText, headers, config;

                data = response.data;
                status = response.status;
                statusText = response.statusText;
                headers = response.headers;
                config = response.config;

                result = data;

                return result;

            });
    };

}]);
```

And in my view, it's as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="conceptCtrl" class="container" ng-init="init()">
    <div ng-repeat="concept in concepts" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>{{concept.id}}. {{query_string}}</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <th>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Description</td>
                        </th>
                        <tr ng-repeat="definition in getDefinitions(concept.id)">
                            <td>{{definition.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{definition.description}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

But this gives an error in Angular: `Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop` (documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D)).

So I was thinking about nesting the various PHP calls into a single JSON... but I have no idea how to do that. Any and all thoughts MUCH MUCH appreciated!!!

EDIT 1:

It was pointed out that I forgot the PHP/SQL code!

PHP is as follows:

query_concepts.php

```
<?php
    require_once './config.php';

    $conceptData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    foreach ($conceptData as $key=>$value) {
        $_POST[$key]=$value;
    }

    $data = $_POST;

    $concept_ids = $data['id'];

    $in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($concept_ids), '?'));

    try {
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `concepts` WHERE id IN (" . $in . ")");
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($concept_ids as &$id) {
            $i++;
            $query->bindParam($i, $id);
        }
        $query->execute();
#        $query->debugDumpParams();
        $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo $json_response = json_encode($results);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

query_definitions.php:

```
<?php
    require_once './config.php';

    $conceptData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    foreach ($conceptData as $key=>$value) {
        $_POST[$key]=$value;
    }

    $data = $_POST;

    $search_term = $data['query_string'];

    try {
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `definitions` WHERE concept_id = ?");
        $query->bindParam(1, $search_term);
        $query->execute();
        $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo $json_response = json_encode($results);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code? Your SQL?

Comment: @symcbean thanks for pointing that out, added it!